# android - app installation

Tags: android

i developed a application and it works fine on the emulator, so tried to install it on my phone using a .apk of the file
(**NOTE**: It is a unSigned one).

on installing the app on the phone, during installation i get a error as installation failed.
(**NOTE**: Other applications from the market are installing without any errors, the ones downloaded from the internet are working fine, but one developed by me aren't)

tried to debug the application on my phone using USB debugging.

the app gets installed fine by USB debugging.

Still can't figure out how to install using the .apk file.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign your application if you do not want to install it using adb. If you use Eclipse and ADT just click on your project folder, choose Android tools -> Export Signed Application Package. Then provide access (or create new) to your keystore file and choose key. After you've signed an application you can, for instance, send it by email and install it on a real smartphone.

Comment: so i cant install a unsigned application ?

Comment: You can but only through ADB. What is the problem to sign it?

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is copy the .apk to the phone via the ISB cable into the sim card out the SD card. Then you don't have to send any emails to yourself.

Comment: Thats what i did, but on installing... the app doesnt completes installation.

Comment: The .apk must be signed for the device to install it. As mentioned before its very easy, but it must be signed.